# Is it possible to access lan when using vpn?

Tags: java, android, vpn

I'm building an app, and I need to access some data in `lan` with a given address(Say 192.168.11.222), I use `HttpUrlConnection` to do my work, and this is just fine when I did not launch a `vpn` connection using other app(Say shadowsocks android), but when I using `vpn` established by other app, I just get an exception

> java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp.Address@9727cf6d.

I tried using `openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY)`, and that just does'nt help, anyone know how to figure it out? 
Since I can't close `vpn` in some cases.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know if you use a VPN Connection you will get a WLAN instead of a LAN, so the device connected to a VPN will have access to the machines of your LAN and the network of the VPN. The problem here is when the network of LAN and the VPN network are in the same IP address range. If some machine in your LAN has the same IP address than some machine in your VPN network it will cause conflicts on routing the packages.

So is it possible to access lan when using VPN? Yes, but you have to take into account the previous explanation and be sure that the machines won't have the same IP so you don't have problems to access resources

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,but i am still a bit confused ,can you please make a further explanation or provide me some information links? I'm new in android ,thanks.